# Is it possible to use TSServer instead of tsc to validate all source files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to manage my TypeScript projects. I use the following workflow:

1) I (only) transpile the projects using the `ts-loader` plugin in `webpack`:

```js
use: [{
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: {
        transpileOnly: true
    }
}
```

2) I validate my sources using `tsc` and the `noEmit` option in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
}
```

3) I run the `npm` script from Visual Studio Code  as tasks and this works as expected.

```js
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "type-check",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

While editing in Visual Studio Code I receive immediate visual feedback from the `TSServer` that runs in the background but only shows me the problems in one specific file.

Is it possible to use `TSServer` to validate all files in a project instead of manually running the `tsc` cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing "View" > "Problems"? It should list *all* issues in your current project.

[image]

The downside, depending on your preferences, is that it'll also show errors from other tools - eslint, tslint, type-coverage, etc.

Comment: Sure, I use that all the time but without running `tsc` as task it only shows me the problems in the currently open source file.

Comment: It shouldn't. The above is without running tsc as a client task. Did you open your project folder? Do you have a tsconfig.json there?

Comment: Strange. It sees as if VSC would do exactly what I expected but I does not work for me. I always open the project folder as my root and it contains the tsconfig.json file that i also use when executing my tasks. I sometimes see the JS/TS Language services starting in the status bar of VSC when opening a file but then all other messages disappear and I only see the ones for the specific open file. Only when running tsc again I see all messages.

Comment: I just found an SR (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953) that suggests that it is currently not possible. I’m really interested on how your solution works!